# Elastic Search, field name starting with at sign

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch 1.3.4 and groovy. What I am trying to do is a using script in elastic search query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "2014-12-08T03:40:00.000Z",
              "lte": "2014-12-08T03:40:59.999Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": []
    }
  },
  "facets": {
    "myFacet": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "doc['@field1'].value + ':' + doc['@field2'].value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For some reason, the field name starts with the at sign. The problem is that groovy treats the at sign as a special character(http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators). Error messages from groovy:

> nested: GroovyScriptCompilationException[MultipleCompilationErrorsException[startup failed:\nScript78.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class field , unable to find class for annotation\n @

So is it possible to make groovy working with field starting with a "@" sign?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the "@" with the unicode value ?  e.g. doc['\u0040field1'].value

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the "@" with the [unicode value](http://unicode-table.com/en/) will prevent it being processed by Groovy

e.g. replace

```
doc['@field1'].value
```

with

```
doc['\u0040field1'].value
```